# Why getView mix my rows?

Tags: android, android-listview

GetView method set data correctly. I check my mMessageList item tag and inflate coresponding layout but on scrolling getView mix them. How can I resolve this problem?

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

    if(convertView == null){
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        if(mMessageList.get(position).getTag() == RespKey.MESSAGE_TAG_CUSTOMER){
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.message_list_row_customer, null);
            viewHolder.messageTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.userMessageText);
            viewHolder.messageImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.userMessageIcon);
        } else {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.message_list_row_driver, null);
            viewHolder.messageTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.driverMessageText);
            viewHolder.messageImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.driverMessageIcon);
        }
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
      } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    viewHolder.messageTextView.setText(mMessageList.get(position).getMessage());
    return convertView;
}

public static class ViewHolder{

    public TextView messageTextView;
    public ImageView messageImageView;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this use case you have to override `getViewTypeCount` and `getItemViewType` . The former returns the number of different `convertView` you need. In your case it should be 2. The latter returns the type of the `convertView`.  E.x.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (mMessageList.get(position).getTag() == RespKey.MESSAGE_TAG_CUSTOMER) {
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
 }
```

getItemViewType has always to return an int between `0` and `getViewTypeCount - 1`. This is very important. Internally, this value is used to access an array of `convertView`

Comment: i will return 0 and 1  or RespKey.MESSAGE_TAG_CUSTOMER and RespKey.MESSAGE_TAG_DRIVER?

Comment: if  RespKey.MESSAGE_TAG_CUSTOMER and RespKey.MESSAGE_TAG_DRIVER are int with value 0 and 1 you should return the constants.

Comment: If I have 5views can I with if/else case check its tag and return 0,1,2,3,4?

Comment: if/else or switch. You will have to adjust `getViewTypeCount` as well